# Temporal property optimization with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, temporal

I want to implement temporal properties using an approach similar to that described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120915092356/http://blog.lowendahl.net/?p=190), using Entity Framework code-first for database storage.

I want it optimized for getting the current value and have lazy loading for the history, but I don't want to have to add boilerplate code in the parent entity for every usage, as is the approach in the link above.

At the moment I have something like the code below, which by convention results in the database schema as shown below the code.

This will function as I need, but for performance reasons I'd like to avoid the join it requires to get the current property value (i.e. I want to move the TemporalStrings.CurrentValue DB column to Entities.Name instead).

If I try

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(o => o.Name.CurrentValue).HasColumnName("Name");
```

it doesn't work. I get an exception like

```
The type 'ConsoleApplication1.TemporalString' has already been configured as an entity type. It cannot be reconfigured as a complex type.
```

Is there some way I can achieve this mapping, or is there a better approach for achieving this functionality?

Code:

```
public class TemporalString
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CurrentValue { get; set; } // Setter would be customized to append to History.
    public virtual List<TemporalStringValue> History { get; set; }
    // Other methods such as string ValueAt(DateTime) would exist.
}

public class TemporalStringValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveFrom { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TemporalString Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TemporalString> TemporalStrings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TemporalStringValue> TemporalStringValues { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().Property(o => o.Name.CurrentValue).HasColumnName("Name");
        // TODO: Map DB column TemporalStrings.CurrentValue to DB column Entities.Name?
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestDbContext>());
        using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            var entity = new Entity
                             {
                                 Name = new TemporalString
                                            {
                                                CurrentValue = "Current Value",
                                                History = new List<TemporalStringValue>
                                                              {
                                                                  new TemporalStringValue
                                                                      {
                                                                          EffectiveFrom = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                                          Value = "Current Value"
                                                                      },
                                                                  new TemporalStringValue
                                                                      {
                                                                          EffectiveFrom = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-1),
                                                                          Value = "Old Value"
                                                                      },
                                                                  new TemporalStringValue
                                                                      {
                                                                          EffectiveFrom = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-2),
                                                                          Value = "Older Value"
                                                                      }
                                                              }
                                            }
                             };
            context.Entities.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        Console.Write("Done.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Resulting schema:

```
Entities
(PK) Id
(FK) Name_Id (references TemporalStrings.Id)

TemporalStrings
(PK) Id
     CurrentValue

TemporalStringValues
(PK) Id
     EffectiveFrom
     Value
(FK) TemporalString_Id
```

Desired schema:

```
Entities
(PK) Id
(FK) Name_Id (references TemporalStrings.Id)
     Name (formerly TemporalStrings.CurrentValue)

TemporalStrings
(PK) Id

TemporalStringValues
(no change)
```

Comment: I don't know how you expect to avoid a join from `Entities` to `TemporalStrings`. How do you expect `TemporalStrings` to be updated when you change the value of `Entities`? If you read the property then you can get away with caching the `Name` in your `Entity`. Otherwise, you need to set something up akin to a `OnPropertyChangedEvent` that updates the `TemporalString` so it has the most recent change when you write to `Name`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this Mike. I'm not sure if I understand your questioning completely. I have updated my question to try to make it more clear.

Comment: In terms of updating the temporal property value, I've got my implementation set up so that when `entity.Name.CurrentValue = "New Value"` is executed, the setter also appends to the History with the current date/time and the new value. So the current value will always be simultaneously held in `entity.Name.CurrentValue` and the latest `entity.Name.History` entry.

Comment: I've also added the desired schema at the bottom of the question to make that clear. I'd like to be able to get something like `name = context.Entities.First().Name.CurrentValue` without having to join to the `TemporalStrings` table.

Comment: `TemporalStrings` serves no purpose in your new schema. Unless you want to re-use the table across multiple tables.

Comment: Hi Mike. I am indeed reusing the TemporalString class across multiple entities and sometimes even multiple times on the same entity. For example, for the code above you might also have on the `Entity` class something like `public virtual TemporalString Description { get; set; }`.

Comment: Very interesting question. Have you solved this the way you wanted, or perhaps you found another way of doing it? Could you answer your own question if so? I would love to see your final approach here.

Comment: Hi @julealgon. I'm using this temporal property approach successfully but I haven't found an answer to this question, which would be a good performance improvement. I'm able to get away with the performance hit in the system I'm working with due to the nature of the data volume, etc. If a solution could be found it would make a great generic way to deal with temporal properties.